# Converting all underscore connected letters to uppercase in php

Tags: php, regex, camelcasing

I have a string like "kp_o_zmq_k" and I need to covert it to "kpOZmqK" where I need to convert all letters connected to the right of the underscore(o,z,k in this case) to uppercase.

Comment: You mean, you want to convert letters that have a preceding underscore to upper-case?

Comment: Because simply 'connected' would imply that p and q should also be upper-case.

Comment: What did you come up with? What have you tried?

Comment: What is supposed to happen if you have two underscores in a row? Something like `sadf__ety__hjk`

Comment: Yes, I want to convert letters preceding underscore to uppercase

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with [preg_replace_callback](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.preg-replace-callback.php) function in php.

```
$ptn = "/_[a-z]?/";
$str = "kp_o_zmq_k";
$result = preg_replace_callback($ptn,"callbackhandler",$str);
// print the result
echo $result;

function callbackhandler($matches) {
    return strtoupper(ltrim($matches[0], "_"));
}
```

Answer (score 7):

```
<?php
function underscore2Camelcase($str) {
  // Split string in words.
  $words = explode('_', strtolower($str));

  $return = '';
  foreach ($words as $word) {
    $return .= ucfirst(trim($word));
  }

  return $return;
}
?>
```