# Specific uppercase editing

Tags: php, html, css

I need to set uppercase letters to every word in the text starting from the second one.
These words always have an underscore at the beginning and the text does not have a fixed length. I have no clue on how to do this.

Example:

```
input: my_little_green_house

result: my_Little_Green_House
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Converting all underscore connected letters to uppercase in php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15286610/converting-all-underscore-connected-letters-to-uppercase-in-php)

Comment: use `ucwords` and then a bit of your trial

Comment: It is similar, thank you for your reply

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$output = str_replace(" ", "_",lcfirst(ucwords(strtolower(str_replace("_", " ", $input))))
```

Explain:

```
$output = str_replace(" ", "_", // 5. Convert all spaces to underscores again.
          lcfirst( // 4. Lowercase the first character.
              ucwords( // 3. Uppercase first letter of every words
                  strtolower( // 2. Convert to lowercase
                      str_replace("_", " ", $input) // 1. Convert all underscores to spaces
                  )
              )
          )
```

Guys, I intent to make a fiddle but http://phpfiddle.org/ is down, anyone have an alternative php fiddle over here?

Comment: That is it, thank you very much!
I can't vote for your answer because my rank is too low.